# Unable to insert the symbols in the textbox at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a textbox and a edit button beside it,when i click on the edit buttton a popover containing symbol buttons appear.

Then when you click on respective symbol,it appears in the textbox.But,it is appending one after the other on respective symbol button click.I need the symbol to be inserted wherever the cursor is placed in the textbox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="symboltext"> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="popbutton" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group" role="group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="regbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="copyrightbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"><span></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="trademarkbtn"><sup>TM</sup></button></div>';

$('#popbutton').popover({
    animation: true,
    content: popupElement,
    html: true
});


$(document).on('click', "#trademarkbtn", function () {
    $("#symboltext").val($("#symboltext").val()+"\u2122 " );
});

$(document).on('click', "#regbtn", function () {
    $("#symboltext").val($("#symboltext").val()+"\u00AE ")
});

$(document).on('click', "#copyrightbtn", function () {
    $("#symboltext").val($("#symboltext").val()+"\u00A9 " )
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/70tkhpvg/3/)

Comment: Not sure I understand. The code seems to work for me. I made this:` © This © Works ™ for me ® `

Comment: `var v=$("#symboltext")[0]; $("#symboltext").val( v.value.slice(0, v.selectionStart)+ "BLAH" + v.value.slice(v.selectionStart+1));`

Comment: @cory first insert sometext then place cursor in middle of any word and try to insert symbol

Comment: Yes how can i help you?

Comment: Related to the same question,but different requirement.[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832206/how-to-use-the-same-function-for-inserting-symbols-appear-on-popover) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

create function to get cursor position

```
function textbox()
{
 var ctl = document.getElementById('symboltext');
 var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
 var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
 return {s:startPos,e:endPos};
}
```

create function to insert value at specific index

```
function getVal(insert){
 var val=$("#symboltext").val();
 var index = textbox();
 val = val.slice(0,index.s) + insert + val.slice(index.s)
 return val;
}
```

call function like this

```
$(document).on('click', "#regbtn", function () {
 var val=getVal("\u00AE ");
 $("#symboltext").val(val);  
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/70tkhpvg/9/)

Comment: try to insert multiple symbols in one go,it's not working.Only for once the symbol is inserting at cursor point.After that,it is appending at the end.

Comment: because when you click on symbol blur function of textbox will fire which means no cursor exists now in textbox.

Comment: is there anyway to getover that ?

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832206/how-to-use-the-same-function-for-inserting-symbols-appear-on-popover) here